# How to make field wider?

Tags: css

Im trying to make wider field of "last post" in phpBB. I edited CSS "lastpost" class from 250 to 300 value but looks like left fields are not responsible so extended field goes on next line and forum's list get f*ed up. What I should edit more?

Address of phpBB is: http://schiza.me

Thanks

Comment: Please show your code...

Comment: you need to scale the table before you change last post, it is hard to tell what you want without farther elaboration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change multiple selectors.
Here is an example :

```
dd.lastpost, dd.redirect, dd.moderation, dd.time, dd.info {
width: 300px;
font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

Other table lines will need to always keep the same total size you will migth want to change an other property like that one for th number of topics and views :

```
dd.posts, dd.topics, dd.views {
    width: 75px;
}
```

Comment: I thought I can wide "lastpost" by make auto-size"forums" row  a narrow (automatically). So I cant imagine that your code will be work because if follow logic , its still will moves one next line. Or maybe I just get you wrong